# Is there any reason for people who can program to use Squarespace or Shopify instead of Wordpress and WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shopify, squarespace

I'm currently running all my websites on:

- CakePHP 3.7.3
- WordPress

I am not sure if these 2 tools are still the best to use in 2020. I'm wondering if I should consider something else than CakePHP/Wordpress, e.g. using Squarespace or Shopify in the future.
I'm also considering using Laravel instead of CakePHP and possibly ReactJS, although the latter one seems to have more of a learning curve for me.

What I like about CakePHP and WordPress is that they have been around for 10 years and I can keep updating them without having to worry about their product dying. Although CakePHP doesn't seem to be the #1 solution in webdevelopment-land anymore for many years.

It seems they are largely marketing to non-techs wanting to have their own blog or webshop. Does that mean there is no reason for people who are decent webdevelopers to use their products?

Comment: The way this question is written, it is asking for opinions which is not a good fit for StackExchange sites. Opinion-based and debate questions are off-topic here ([see this post on good subjective questions which work here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective)). Can you reword your question in a way that fits the site requirements?

Answer (score 0):

It really comes down to your priorities with the project. Investing time directly in the technology means less time to focus on business concerns. Would your time be better spent focused on search engine optimization, client experiences, or conversion rate optimization? You might have the fastest loading website in the industry, but horrible user outcomes.

Products such as squarespace or shopify will allow you to focus on the business and product you are trying to deliver with much less focus on the technology at play. The trade off is that you give up a lot of control of the actual website, and may not be able to fully capture everything in the way you want it.

If you are in a good place with the website to continue to invest in technology directly, it is certainly a good idea to experiment with alternatives. Laravel is a very clean and easy to work with framework.

React does have a lot of learning curve. It's a good option, but there are also alternatives. You should think carefully about your specific needs in a front end framework. vue.js is less of a learning curve than react and very commonly paired with laravel. alpinejs is very young, but is aimed at sites with a lighter frontend framework need and is extremely easy to work with.

I hope something here helps!

a few useful links specific to the technology discussed:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend#writing-vue-components

https://vuejs.org/

https://laraveldaily.com/quick-start-laravel-5-5-vue-js-simple-crud-project/

https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/

https://scrimba.com/g/galpinejs